# Addition of array objects based on date in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object array of the form

```
  var arrayA = [
          {value:3000, date:"01/01/2020"},
          {value:4000, date:"02/13/2020"},
          {value:5500, date:"01/01/2020"},
          {value:2300, date:"03/03/2020"},
          {value:1200, date:"02/13/2020"},
          {value:4000, date:"03/03/2020"}
         ];
```

I want to add values that have the same date and come up with a new array as below.

```
var _new_arrayA = [
       {value:8500, date:"01/01/2020"},
       {value:5200, date:"02/13/2020"},
       {value:6300, date:"03/03/2020"}
     ];
```

I do not know where to start, therefore i don't have any implementation code

Comment: You've shown how the array starts (a), and the expected result (b) but not what gets you from a -> b.

Comment: With `add values` you mean change the value? It's pretty unclear what's your exact problem is. Just use `find` to find one object, then change the value.